# Expresión regular para números telefónicos

Tags: python, regex

Estoy haciendo una expresión para validar todos los formatos de número telefónico posibles. Tengo el 50%, no me está validando los caractéres admitidos de por medio como `* . - whitespace`

Estas son las reglas

> Puede o no contener paréntesis de apertura y cierre
>   ej. (55)
>
> Puede o no contener un '+' dentro de los paréntesis
>   ej. (+52)
>
> Puede tener dos o tres números si existe el paréntesis
>   ej. (+555) o
>   (+55)
>
> Puede haber un espacio entre el paréntesis y los siguientes números
>
> ej. (55) 44332211
>
> Los números consecutivos al paréntesis de cierre deben ser 6 u 8
>   ej.
>   (55)443322 o (55)44332211
>
> Los número consecutivos al paréntesis pueden contener espacios en
>   blanco, guiones, astericos o puntos 
>   ej.(55)44-33-22-11 o (55)44 33 22
>   11 o (55)44*33*22*11 o (55)44.33.22.11
>
> Los números consecutivos al paréntesis pueden estar divididos en
>   grupos de 2, 3 o 4 números 
>   ej, (55)5544-3322 o (55)55 44 33 22 o
>   (555)444*333
>
> El formato puede venir de corrido de 8, 10 o 12 números 
>   ej. 55443322 o
>   5544332211 o 554433221100

Esta es la expresión

```
[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-\s]){3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){4}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){2})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}
```

Este es un mapa de la expresión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Dejo un script de ejemplo, el regex lo estoy haciendo para Python, no se si cambie mucho con JS

Gracias

```js
$(function(){

  $('ul li').each(function(){
    let numero = $(this).text();
    let regex = /^[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-\s]){3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){4}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){2})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}$/;
    let res = regex.test( numero );
    $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' es: ' + res);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Números de teléfono
<ul>
  <li>prueba</li>
  <li>(55)prueba</li>
  <li>(55)333-prueba</li>
  <li>(55)prueba 22</li>
  <li>554433221100</li>
  <li>5544332211</li>
  <li>55443322</li>
  <li>(55)443322</li>
  <li>(55)44332211</li>
  <li>(+55)443322</li>
  <li>(+55)44332211</li>
  <li>(55)4433*2211</li>
  <li>(55)444.333</li>
  <li>(55)44-33-22-11</li>
  <li>(55)4433-2211</li>
  <li>(+55)443 322</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: De momento, no tienes la opción del paréntesis cerrado al final de todo, por lo que el ejemplo: (55) no lo detecta

Comment: Oh, esque (55) no es un número válido, la regla dice que puede o no contener ese match, pero no significa que lo valide así como tal.

Comment: Ah, pue entonces la expresión que estaba haciendo no vale, podrías decirme qué número no es válido entonces?

Comment: por ejemplo (55)test o 55/44/33/22 o 45309485304958309458309458 o 22

Comment: Entonces, del test que has puesto en tu ejemplo, ¿Cuál no pasa y debería pasar? porque veo que los que pasa son números válidos y los que no, no lo son.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el enunciado es algo inconsistente.

Si el número completo puede ser de 8, 10 o 12 dígitos, entonces, cuando hay dos dígitos entre paréntesis debiese aceptar 6, 8 o 10 dígitos a continuación. Es más. Si hay tres dígitos en el paréntesis, debiera aceptar 5, 7 o 9 números.

Como sea, hice una expresión regular que comprueba que se cumpla una de las condiciones:

1. inicio del argumento, paréntesis, opcionalmente un +, dos o tres dígitos, cierra paréntesis, 6 ocurrencias de "un dígito seguido opcionalmente de *.- o espacio", 2 ocurrencias opcionales de "un dígito seguido opcionalmente de *.- o espacio", fin del argumento

o bien

2. inicio del argumento, 8 ocurrencias de "un dígito seguido opcionalmente de *.- o espacio", 2 ocurrencias opcionales de "un dígito seguido opcionalmente de *.- o espacio", 2 ocurrencias opcionales de "un dígito seguido opcionalmente de *.- o espacio", fin del argumento

Básicamente, o tienes los paréntesis o no los tienes. Pero no se me ocurre cómo hacer que el paréntesis de cierre sea obligatorio sólo si lo has abierto.

Por otro lado, no hay cómo decir, en una expresión regular: "8, 10 o 12" dígitos. Siempre puedes decirle: "entre 8 y 12 ocurrencias", pero no tramos discretos. Por eso le puse 8, seguido de dos dígitos o ninguno, seguido de dos dígitos o ninguno. Y en ambos casos, no acepto más argumentos porque un dígito adicional no es válido.

Respecto a lo que dije al comienzo: en realidad la solución completa incluye una verificación adicional para cuando hay 3 dígitos dentro del paréntesis. Sin embargo, como también dije, el enunciado es inconsistente porque explícitamente permite `(+555)12345678` lo cual totaliza 11 dígitos y no cumple con la cláusula final que deben ser 8,10 o 12.

```js
var regex = /^(\(\+?\d{2,3}\)[\*|\s|\-|\.]?(([\d][\*|\s|\-|\.]?){6})(([\d][\s|\-|\.]?){2})?|(\+?[\d][\s|\-|\.]?){8}(([\d][\s|\-|\.]?){2}(([\d][\s|\-|\.]?){2})?)?)$/;

var fixtures = {
  "acepta numero con paréntesis":"(55)123456",
  "acepta numero sin paréntesis":"55123456",
  "acepta numero con + dentro del paréntesis":"(+55)123456",
  "acepta tres números dentro del paréntesis":"(+555)123456",
  "rechaza cuatro números dentro del paréntesis":"(+6555)123456",
  "acepta espacio entre el paréntesis y los siguientes números":"(+555) 123456",
  "Acepta 6 dígitos luego del paréntesis":"(55)443322",
  "Acepta 8 dígitos luego del paréntesis":"(55)44332211",
  "Rechaza 7 dígitos luego del paréntesis":"(55)4433221",
  "acepta guiones intercalados": "(55)44-33-22-11",
"acepta espacios intercalados": "(55)44 33 22 11",
"acepta asteriscos intercalados": "(55)44*33*22*11",
"acepta puntos intercalados": "(55)44.33.22.11",
"rechaza comas intercaladas": "(55)44,33,22,11",
"acepta 8 números de corrido": "12345678",
"acepta 10 números de corrido": "1234567890",
"acepta 12 números de corrido": "123456789012",
"acepta 10 números espaciados": "55 2030 4050",
"acepta 10 números espaciados con un + adelante":"+55 20 50 4444",
"rechaza 11 números de corrido": "12345678901",
};
for (let fixture in fixtures) {
   console.log(fixture,fixtures[fixture],regex.test(fixtures[fixture]));
}
```

Comment: Casi perfecto mi hermano, solo me puedes apoyar con: +55 20 50 4444 y 55 2030 4050?

Comment: ambos deben reconocerse como válidos? Hice un cambio para aceptar un + antes de la secuencia de 8, 10 o 12 números ya sea de corrido o separados.

Answer (score 2):

Después de pensarlo un tiempo, me di cuenta de que te aceptaba los patrones si acababan en ***** **-** o en un espacio, por lo que pude modificar la expresión así:

```
[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-]){2}\d{3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){3}\d{2}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){1}\d{4})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}
```

Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar en cada patrón lo siguiente:

Tenías:

```
(\d{3}[\*\.\-]){3}
```

por lo que tenía que terminar en uno de esos 3 caracteres.
Yo lo he cambiado por:

```
(\d{3}[\*\.\-]){2}\d{3}
```

Para que acabe en tres dígitos. Eso repetido para los tres grupos.

Te pongo el código arreglado:

```js
$(function(){

  $('ul li').each(function(){
    let numero = $(this).text();
    let regex = /^[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-\s]){2}\d{3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){3}\d{2}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){1}\d{4})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}$/;
    let res = regex.test( numero );
    $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' es: ' + res);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Números de teléfono
<ul>
  <li>prueba</li>
  <li>(55)prueba</li>
  <li>(55)333-prueba</li>
  <li>(55)prueba 22</li>
  <li>554433221100</li>
  <li>5544332211</li>
  <li>55443322</li>
  <li>(55)443322</li>
  <li>(55)44332211</li>
  <li>(+55)443322</li>
  <li>(+55)44332211</li>
  <li>(55)4433*2211</li>
  <li>(55)444.333</li>
  <li>(55)44-33-22-11</li>
  <li>(55)4433-2211</li>
  <li>(+55)443 322</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Código de expresiones regulares para telefonos de España :

```
er_telefono = r'(\+34|0034|34)?[ -]*(6|7)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){8}'
er_telefono_madrid = '(91)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){7}'
er_telefono_alava = '(945)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){7}'
er_telefono_albacete = '(967)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){7}'

telefonos_espanya = [['Madrid',er_telefono_madrid]]
telefonos_espanya.append(['Álava',er_telefono_alava])
telefonos_espanya.append(['Albacete',er_telefono_albacete])

if (not re.match(er_telefono,telefono)) :
    for x in telefonos_espanya :
        provincia = x[0]
        patron = x[1]
        b_encontrado=False
        if (re.match(patron,telefono)) :
            print ("Teléfono de ",provincia)
            b_encontrado=True
            break
    if (not b_encontrado) : 
        print ("Teléfono incorrecto.")
        b_erroneo=True
        continue
else :
    print ("Teléfono móvil")
```